# Android 8 Bug: Starting apk installation via adb doesn't work, needs permission REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES

Tags: android, installation, apk, android-8.0-oreo, packageinstaller

I need to start the installation of an apk on an android 8 phone, but this should not be silent (adb install). The behavior should be as if the user has touched the apk file on the device.
Before android 8 it was possible to launch the installation of an apk by adb like this:

```
adb shell am start -d file:"///sdcard/foobar.apk" -p com.google.android.packageinstaller
```

This is not possible anymore on android 8. According to the log file the permission android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES is necessary.

```
09-25 16:39:55.691  6066  6066 E InstallStart: Requesting uid 2000 needs to declare permission android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES
```

I know that since android 8 [apps that requests installing other apps needs this permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES), but this shouldn't be the case by doing it via adb, right?

Is this a bug in android 8? Is it somehow possible to do it in an other way?

Answer (score 12):

Try adding in Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
```